# How a multiplier circuit could be implemented in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logic, multiplication, circuit

TBH I have a hard time understanding the logic gate diagrams because I haven't yet fully understood the low-level electronics equipment and how that all works.

I have had a little bit of experience learning about basic logic gates and after watching a few videos and thinking about it a lot I can understand it for a few minutes before it slips away.

But then I saw some examples of "logic gates" "implemented" in software and it made much more sense what's going on. For example, [here](https://gist.github.com/shawndumas/446aa4f79b8ec0b34bf1).

Then I even was able to go further and understand how a [full adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder) works, as in [here](https://www.mikedoesweb.com/2013/full-adders-32-bit-adders-in-javascript/):

```
function fullAdder(a,b,c){
  return {
    c:or(and(xor(a,b),c), and(a,b)), // C is the carry
    s:xor(xor(a,b),c) // S is the sum
  };
}
```

That's pretty basic compared to the logic diagrams.

Now I would like to understand how [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier) and [division](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256665/how-to-build-a-division-logic-circuit) are implemented in logic gates, such as like x86's [MUL](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html) operator.

```
function MUL(a,b){
  return {
    ...
  };
}
```

I don't know really where to begin though other than dedicating some serious time to understanding a multiplier circuit and trying to translate that into perhaps a NAND gate implementation using the examples above. Wondering if one who knows this already can demonstrate the implementation in JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier

Comment: Alternative carry logic: `c:or(and(a, b), and(a, c), and(b, c))` / `c:nand(nand(a, b), nand(a, c), nand(b, c))`

Comment: `I would like to understand how [division is] implemented in logic gates` best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication relies of the way numbers are encoded in binary.
If A is unsigned and coded by bits a_n-1,a_n-2,...,a_1,a_0, its value is
A=a_n-1*2^n-1+a_n-2*2^n-2+...+a_1*2^1+a_0

So to multiply A×B, you have to do
A×B=A×(b_n-1*2^n-1+b_n-2*2^n-2+...+b_1*2^1+b_0)
       = A×b_n-1*2^n-1+A×b_n-2*2^n-2+...+A×b_1*2^1+A×b_0
and multiplication is just a big addition where every term A×b_i*2^i is either A×2^i if b_i==1 or 0 if b_i==0

Here is an implementation in C

```
int mult(unsigned short A, unsigned short B){
  int res=0;
  int mask=0x1;
  for(int i=0; i<16;i++,mask<<=1){
    if(B&mask)
      res += (A << i);
  }
  return res;
}
```

The test on b_i can be replaced by an 'and' gate.

```
int mult(unsigned short A, unsigned short B){
  int res=0;
  int mask=0x1;
  for(int i=0; i<16;i++,mask<<=1){
     res += (A&~(((B&mask)>>i) -1))<<i;
  }
  return res;
}
```

This fancy expression extracts ith bit of B (`B&mask`), puts it at LSB (`>>i`), substracts 1, so that we have a 1-1=0 it bit is 1 and a -1=0xffffffff otherwise. We just have to complement and to do the "and" with A to get either A or 0 depending on ith bit. Fortunately, things are easier in hardware. It is sufficient to duplicate bit b_i of B and to do an "and" with   every bit of A.

To simplify hardware, the variable shift of `A<<i` can be replaced by a 1 bit left shift of A at every step (`A=A<<1`). And a similar modification can be done for b_i extraction in such a way that we always consider the LSB of B.

```
int mult(unsigned short A, unsigned short B){
  int res=0;
  int mask=0x1;
  for(int i=0; i<16;i++){
     res += A&~((B&mask) -1);
     A <<= 1;
     B >>= 1;
  }
  return res;
}
```

This is more or less how a simple multiplier looks in hardware, once the loop is unrolled.
You can implement it in js and replace the + by an adder done with gates and use simulated "and" gates.

Actually, hardware multipliers are a bit more complex.

- they use a special adder without carry propagation to reduce addition time (carry save addition). This requires an extra addition at the end of the computation
- they frequently use base 4 to reduce the number of adding steps (modified Booth algorithm).
- they are pipelined to improve throughput

BTW, you may be interested by this [online simulator](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/koren/arith/simulator/) of the different computer arithmetic algorithms.